# Blog Comments MVC simple Creating new comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problems getting my blog create comments working it works fine when I edit in the db putting the relation id in but I cannot get it when I use the form.

Error is here: Blogposts = id

```
   public ActionResult BlogPost(int Id)
        {
            var _getSpecificBlogPost = db.Blogposts.Where(m => m.Id == Id).ToList();
            return View(_getSpecificBlogPost);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BlogComment_Create(string name, string bodytext, string id )
        {
            BlogComment model = new BlogComment { Name = name, BodyText = bodytext, Blogposts = id};
            db.BlogComments.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
        }
```

In `BlogComment` I have:      `public virtual Blogpost Blogposts { get; set; }`

In `BlogPosts` I have:        `public virtual ICollection<BlogComment> BlogComments { get; set; }`

```
<form method="post" id="form-variant-create" action="@Url.Action("BlogComment_Create", "Blog")" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                <br />
                <textarea name="bodytext" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="id" value="@foreach(var item in Model){@item.Id}" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is the error and what is the expected outcome? Please rewrite the question to include the code needed to reproduce your issue. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlogPosts is from BlogPost type. you need to create a property for your BlogPostId as ForeignKey.

```
public virtual int BlogPostId{get;set;}
```

Insert this line into your CommentModel. and then reffer to this instead of BlogPosts.

and edit your BlogPosts Property too.

```
[ForeignKey("BlogPostId")]
public virtual Blogpost Blogposts { get; set; }
```